# Using Flink LocalEnvironment for Production

Tags: apache-flink

I wanted to understand the limitations of LocalExecutionEnvironment and if it can be used to run in production ?

Appreciate any help/insight. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalExecutionEnvironment spins up a Flink MiniCluster, which runs the entire Flink system (JobManager, TaskManager) in a single JVM. So you're limited to CPU cores and memory available on that one machine. You also don't have HA from multiple JobManagers. I haven't looked at other limitations of the MiniCluster environment, but I'm sure more exist.

Answer (score 2):

A LocalExecutionEnvironment doesn't load a config file on startup, so you have to do all of the configuration in the application. By default it also doesn't offer a REST endpoint. You can solve both these issues by doing something like this:

```
String cwd = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
Configuration conf = GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration(cwd);
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(conf);
```

Logging may be another issue that will require a workaround.

I don't believe you'll be able to use the Flink CLI to control the job, but if you create the Web UI (as shown above) you can at least use the REST API to do things like triggering savepoints (after first using the REST API to get the job ID).