# Copy file from local filesystem to AWS S3 using Apache Flink

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I have been trying to setup `Apache Flink` locally on my mac and trying to copy a local file using DataSet API. The copy seems to be working fine, but, I dont see the file being copied to `AWS S3`. I have tried searching the net for any sample, but, I haven't found the resources useful. I am not seeing any trace either after putting in the access key and secret key details in `flink.conf`. How to trace such errors?

Comment: One strategy for debugging Flink jobs is to run in an IDE, and use some combination of stepping through the app, setting breakpoints, printing things, etc. to see what's going on. Have you tried to make a local copy of the file first? That will tell you if the problem is S3 specific.

Comment: If you are running in an IDE, or otherwise using a so-called mini cluster, then Flink won't read `flink-conf.yaml`. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I have installed Flink on mac. Not sure if it is a mini cluster though. Just did brew instal flink and changed the `flink-conf.yaml`

Comment: Are you starting a Flink cluster to which you submit a job, probably via `flink run ... myjob.jar`, or is everything running in an single JVM? If the latter, then `flink-conf.yaml` is being ignored.

Comment: Yes `flink-conf.yaml` is being ignored. Are there any proper documentation which works around tis process?

Comment: Yes, see the code I shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478292/2000823